# Height of div element returns zero

Tags: javascript, html, height

Does anyone know why the height could be zero here?

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
                alert($("#hello").height());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="hello" class="browseIMG" src="https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/64132_926c_10.jpg" />
```

Comment: It give me 422 alert...

Comment: I've put the code into a snippet - but ironically the code now works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because even after DOM loaded successfully, you are getting the height of the image before even the image loading from network.

Probably you have to do that in load event of image.

```
$('#hello').load(function() {  
  alert($("#hello").height());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete `document.ready` function because it's returning the height of element before actually loading it.

```js
alert($("#hello").height());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="hello" class="browseIMG" src="https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/64132_926c_10.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

because your element has not be loaded yet, try this:

```js
    $("#hello").load(function () {
                alert($("#hello").height());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="hello" class="browseIMG" src="https://udemy-images.udemy.com/course/750x422/64132_926c_10.jpg" />
```